# In JavaScript, what is event.isTrigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this in some JS code I was working on:

```
if ( typeof( e.isTrigger ) == 'undefined' ) {
// do some stuff            
}
```

This seems to be part of jQuery. As far as I can see it tells you if an event originated with the user or automatically.

Is this right? And given that it's not documented, is there a way of finding such things out without going behind the curtain of the jQuery API?

Comment: That's pretty ugly. `if (!e.isTrigger)` is how that should be written. If jQuery ever starts setting it to `false` explicitly, this code will break in a pretty messy way.

Comment: As `e.isTrigger` is not documented, it isn't promised to be kept in future releases and shouldn't be used in your production code.

Comment: Indeed is not available anymore in jQuery..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In jQuery 1.7.2 (unminified) line 3148 contains `event.isTrigger = true;` nested within the trigger function. So yes, you are correct - this is only flagged when you use `.trigger()` and is used internally to determine how to handle events.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at jQuery github project, inside trigger.js file line 49 ([link here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9935b6d2db9e1be4bed12f7419e98cdca45763e/src/event/trigger.js#L49)) you can find how isTrigger gets calculated.

[image]

If you add a trigger in your JavaScript and debug through, You can see how the breakpoint reaches this codeline (*checked in jQuery-2.1.3.js for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907765/jquery-why-does-trigger-method-call-it-three-times/33908785#33908785)*)

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers fight against popup windows opened by automated scripts, not real users clicks. If you don't mind promptly opening and closing a window for a real user click and showing a blocked popup window warning for an automated click then you may use this way:

```
button.onclick = (ev) => {

  // Window will be shortly shown and closed for a real user click.
  // For automated clicks a blocked popup warning will be shown.
  const w = window.open();
  if (w) {
    w.close();
    console.log('Real user clicked the button.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Automated click detected.');
};
```