# Passing a variable through the .change() event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some chained select elements for year, make, model, submodel, color. The first one populates through a getJSON call at load time:

```
$.getJSON("http://mydomain/something.cfm?get=years",
    function(json) {
        var data = "";
        $.each(json, function(i, v) {
            if(v.name != ""){
                data = data + "<option value='" + v.value + "'>" + v.name + "</option>";
            }
        });
        $(wheelBuilder.YEARS).html(data).removeAttr("disabled");
        if(getUrlVars()["year"] != undefined){
            $(wheelBuilder.YEARS).val(getUrlVars()["year"]);
            $(wheelBuilder.YEARS).change();
        }
    }
);
```

The subsequent select elements populate when the user selects an item. An .change() function makes a .getJSON() call to get the data to populate each subsequent select element. The getUrlVars() function gets the variables from the query string by name. If they are available, each select element has to be pre-selected. In order for this pre-selection to occur, the .change() function has to be called so that the next element will become populated.

Thing is, I need the code to run inside of these .change() functions only when they are called from onload, not when the user manually makes the changes. I noticed the jquery documentation has a .change( [eventData ], handler ) option for the .change() function, but I'm not exactly sure if this would do the trick or how to use it (no examples provided)

Thanks.

TLDR: Basically, I'm trying to find a way to distinguish when the select option is being selected by code from when the select option is being selected by a human.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways you could do this, but if you're using jquery then probably the easist thing to do is to inspect the event for signs of where the event originated.

Here's a plunkr to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/wfOQgjzwijw3IlN1PlNq?p=preview.

```
var onChange = function(evnt) {
    console.log("Changed: ", arguments)
}

var $select = $("#mySelect");
$select.change(onChange);

// Manually trigger the change event
$select.change();
```

The first event in the console is the one triggered by jQuery. If you manually go and change the combo box you'll get a second event. Here's some differences that I can see:

- jQuery triggered events contain an 'isTriggered' property (see: [In JavaScript, what is event.isTrigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704168/in-javascript-what-is-event-istrigger)). **I'd probably use this one** to determine if the event was triggered internally.
- User triggered events contain a bunch of extra properties, such as: "originalEvent", "bubbles", "cancelable", etc.