# JQuery - Why does Trigger method call it three times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(){
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("select");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_trigger)

Could someone tell me why select event triggered three times after a button click?

It seems that using IE and Chrome can lead different result.

Comment: Strange since calling `$("input").trigger("select");` outside the click and it runs once.

Comment: Try `return false;` after the after()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In IE and Firefox this works fine. Noticed the issue only in Chrome

This seems to be happen because the event gets bubbled up. If you inspect this using Developer tools you can see more information

[image]

If you inspect developer tools at last step breakpoint you can notice isTrigger attribute is true meaning it came from the trigger we have defined.

[image]

The next two hits of the same breakpoint of `$("input").after(" Text marked!");` Developer tools shows almost similar set of attributes. **Notice the bubbles attribute is true**

[image]

Comment: they are not **almost** similar, they are equal(except timeStamp, which can differs by 1ms).

Comment: Yes. But since two functions returns two different objects, that's why I explicitly mentioned as almost.

Answer (score 4):

> JQuery - Why does Trigger method call it three times?

Appear to be called twice at `click` event of `button` ; at

```
$("input").trigger("select");
```

and default handler for `select` event

```
$("input").select(function(){
    $("input").after(" Text marked!");
});
```

To call once at `click` of `button` , or user selection at `input` field , try checking `event.isTrigger` to determine if `event` called by `.trigger()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(e){
      if (!e.isTrigger)
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("select");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input />
<button>click</button>
```

---

alternatively, using `setTimeout` to allow selected text to be cleared before at `click` of `button` before `.trigger("select")` called ; original event handler should be called at most once at `click` of `button` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("input").select(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $("input").after(" Text marked!")
  })

  $("button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("input").trigger("select");
    })
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input />
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704168/in-javascript-what-is-event-istrigger , https://forum.jquery.com/topic/event-istrigger

Comment: Depending on if you use FireFox or Chrome, your above snippet gives different results.  While using Chrome, if you type something into your text input and highlight it, and then click the button, it still prints the message "Text marked!" twice.  Using Firefox, clicking your "click" button does nothing, but highlighting it ("select"-ing it) prints the message "Text marked!" once as one would expect.

Comment: `select` still called twice :)

Comment: But I still confused about why default event trigger twice on Chrome.

Comment: see my answer below @user60627

Comment: @user60627 _"But I still confused about why default event trigger twice on Chrome."_ `value` of `input` still selected when `.trigger("select")` called , triggering default `select` event handler

Comment: @user60627 See updated post ; utilized `setTimeout` to call `event` once

Comment: @vp_arth _"`select` still called twice :) "_ See updated post

Answer (score 3):

Let's see, what happens here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(e){
        console.log(e, e.isTrigger);
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("select");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
```

So, we have 1 `isTrigger` and 2 simple `select` events.

You can to filter `isTrigger` event, but can't to split two other - they are same.

Solution can be to not use `trigger` at all:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mark = 0;
    $("input").select(function(e){
        if(!e.mark) e.mark = ++mark;
        console.log(e, e.mark);
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input")[0].setSelectionRange(0, $('input').val().length, 'forward');
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
```

But! We see it still triggered twice.
I think this bug should be reported to Chrome developers.

---

As solution - need modify your `.select` handler to be idempotent.
and say, on `.blur` reset this handler state.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").one('select',function(){
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("select");
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/10vjtsjt/)**

Comment: I knew that, but i still want to know why i can't use trigger in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should only print once.  If you use FireFox or IE, in fact, it does only print once.  If you adjust the code so that it uses another type of event handler, it only runs once on Chrome as well.

Example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").trigger("focus");
    });
});
</script>
```

Working demonstration of the above:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/3636q8rw/1/

Thus I suspect it is Chrome's "fault" that it prints 3 times.  Notice that using the triggerHandler() method prints the message just once as expected:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_triggerhandler_trigger

Answer (score 0):

Must use :

```
$("input").triggerHandler("select");
```

instead of trigger()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").select(function(){
        $("input").after(" Text marked!");
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input").triggerHandler("select");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
```