# How to see "isTrigger: 3" with Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery

starting from this topic:

[JQuery - Why does Trigger method call it three times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907765/jquery-why-does-trigger-method-call-it-three-times/33908785#33908785)

I want to see the words "isTrigger: 3" as he (Nipuna) has done, please help me

I want to see it at this link: http: //www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp? filename = tryjquery_event_trigger

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu at the top right, More Tools, Developer Tools.

Choose the Sources tab.

Find the JavaScript source with the code that you want to inspect.

Set the breakpoints as shown in the other topic by clicking on the line numbers.

Run the code by some method or refresh the page if it has already run.

The breakpoints should trigger, and then you can view the variables at the right to see their values, such as the `isTrigger` value.