# Why is trigger() triggering the select() handler 3 times?

Tags: javascript

```js
$("#select-test").select(function(e){
    //console.log(e)
    console.log("selected")
})

$("#newTest").click(()=> {
    $("#select-test").trigger("select")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<button id="newTest">TEST ME</button>
<input type="text", id="select-test" value="some">
```

This is in Chrome, in Firefox, it's triggered twice.

I read this [JQuery - Why does Trigger method call it three times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907765/jquery-why-does-trigger-method-call-it-three-times) thread which talked about this issue, but honestly I couldn't understand it.

Somebody said:

```
we have 1 isTrigger and 2 simple select events.
```

What is that mean? 2 simple `select` events? Where? We only have 1 `select` event, where's the second one?

The best answer says that this happens because of bubbling, but... how? I mean, where's the bubbling? I don't see how this explain the event handler being triggered 3 times. Bubbling is when you target a child element, and the parent with the same handler is triggered too, but that's not what we have here. We only have ONE `select` handler, so .. where's the bubbling? And why is it triggered twice in Firefox?

Comment: (if you take the SO link out of the `code` then we'll be able to click it :) )

Comment: When looking at the event objects of the events, there are clearly two events (not three, at least not in FF). Adding line `e.preventDefault();` to the select handler prevents the second event to fire.

Comment: @Teemu where are the two events? `event objects of the events`.. can you be more specific? Isn't there just one event `.select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A select needs a prevent default if you wish to stop it at some point.
the select event isn't the focus event, when a field becomes in focus. The select event gets fired when something is selected.

When you trigger the select event with the below code and have the browser tools open, you will see that the debugger shows the below code. When you select call stack -> dispatch, you can see what triggered the event and see that the third event is triggered by a native event.

[image: call stack]

```js
var count = 0;
$("#select-test").select(function(e){
    if(count == 2) {
       debugger;
    }
    count++;
    console.log("selected")
})

$("#newTest").click(()=> {
    count = 0
    $("#select-test").trigger("select")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<button id="newTest">TEST ME</button>
<input type="text", id="select-test" value="some">
```

If we look at the [documentation for select](https://api.jquery.com/select/) we see this:

> In addition, the default select action on the field will be fired, so the entire text field will be selected.

So what happens is:

1. You trigger select -> jquery fires select to all event handlers
2. jQuery focusses the field, which triggers an automatic browser select all text, which triggers the select event.
3. Jquery selects all text in the field, native select is triggered, which is wrapped by jquery and then passed on to the handlers.

To stop any of these steps from happening you can use `event.preventDefault()` on the first time select is triggered, this will have the side event of not selecting the text.

Rather than using select I suggest you use [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) unless you really need to know what text is selected every time a select is triggered.

Comment: I couldn't understand your explanation. 1 - I thought `tirgger()` triggers the event inside the brackets of the specified element? In the above case, it's the `#select-test` element? Why would ALL elements with `select()` handler be triggered? Which there aren't any other. There's only one. 2 - So.. you're saying that, `trigger()` focuses the `input`, and that causes the browser to automatically select the text inside, which results in the selection happening twice? Then where's the 3rd selection coming from? Your 3rd point is difficult to understand.

Comment: 3 - `native select is triggered` what is that mean? when? During the browser automatic focus, or the first click of the `trigger()`? `wrapped by the jquery` .. what is that mean? `then passed on to the handlers` .. what handlers? Please be more specific with your 3rd point.

Comment: @happy_story select is an event that gets triggered when "text" is selected. In jquery there are 2 types of events. jQuery events, which can be `$('foo').trigger("do_a_dance")` and "native" events, with native events I mean events generated by the browser. So the first time you call trigger, you trigger a jQuery generated event. Then the browser creates an event on the focussing of the field, where the browser selects all the text, this generates a select event. Then jQuery reselects all the text, causing the browser to generate another new select event, all in all 3 events.

Comment: So, let's see if I got this right. On click, `trigger()` triggers the `select()` event on the `input`, which focuses the `input`, and selects the text (1st), then because the `input` was focused, the browser selects the text again (2nd), then because the text was selected again, the `input.select()` is re-triggered again (3rd). Is that correct? And the reason why this only happens twice in Firefox, probably has to do with either the browser not automatically selecting the text on focus, or the `select()` not triggered again by browser selection?

Comment: on the 1st no text is selected, this event is just triggered by you, without an actual selection having happened.

Comment: but when the `select()` event is triggered, doesn't the event selects the text?

Comment: also, when the browser selects the text, and re-triggers the `select()` even again, why does jQuery re-triggers it again since the browser just triggered it?

Comment: I got confused about why isn't this causing an infinite loop? When the browser selects the text, and re-triggers the `select() handler` , why is jQuery trigger it again? And if it does, why is that not causing the browser to again select the text, and cause a loop?

Comment: when you say `the browser creates an event on the focusing of the field`, do you mean the browser triggers `$("#select-test").select()` this event, or it create a new event on this element? And when `select()` is trigger, does it just focus on the input field?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why `.select()` (and also `.on("select")`) trigger three times, but `.one("select")` triggers once :

```js
const $selectTest = $("#select-test");

$selectTest.one("select", function(e){
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log("selected")
});

$("#newTest").click(()=> {
    console.log("Clicked");
    $selectTest.trigger("select")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="newTest">TEST ME</button>
<input type="text", id="select-test" value="some">
```