# Detect Whether an Event is Triggered by User and not programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Well this question has been asked before but in context of jQuery. In **jQuery** we can check it by **originalEvent property** of event Object ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human)) which tells whether its a **manual or programmed event**.

In my case I am **using** **Javascript Event listeners and triggers**. Can we **differentiate between the two kind of events** **(programmed and manual)** in this case?

If not then **any workarounds?**

My Listeners:

```
   function setUpListeners(){
       _cellViewWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown',mouseDownHandler,false);
       _cellViewWrapper.addEventListener('mouseover',mouseEnter,false);
       _cellViewWrapper.addEventListener('blur',blurHandler,true);
       _cellViewWrapper.addEventListener('focus',focusEventHandler,true);
   }`
```

Trigger use Cases:

1. ```
   if(!IE_FLAG) hidePicker();
              //if browser is internet explorer
              else{
                  //if blur is allowed then hide Picker
                  if(_ieBlurAllowed) hidePicker();
                  //if blur is not allowed -- keep focus on picker input
                 //triggering the focus event here
                  else blurredElement.focus(); /
            }
   ```
2. `if((inputElem !== _focussedInput)) setTimeout(function(){ inputElem.focus(); },10);`

and many more...

Comment: jquery is just javascript. If in jquery you can do it, you can do it in js.

Comment: hmmm....any idea how do they do it in jQuery?

Comment: What code is programmatically triggering the event?

Comment: [`event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) - but only partial browser support

Comment: _“In jQuery event object has originalEvent property via which we can tell whether its a manual or programmed event”_ – I doubt that. Documentation only says that certain events may have additional properties than the one the jQuery `Event` object provides, and that `originalPrevent` can be used to access those, as it refers to the native JS Event object. But I don’t see how that would allow to differentiate between an event triggered by the user and one triggered via script.

Comment: @CBroe . You are right. Edited the Question.

Answer (score 22):

In latest browsers, **Event.isTrusted** is available for this particular use-case. As per its [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted):

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via dispatchEvent.

You can simply check inside any event handler:

```
if (e.isTrusted) {
 /* The event is trusted. */
} else {
 /* The event is not trusted. */
}
```

**Browser Support**: Chrome 46.0, Firefox (latest), Opera 33, Safari & IE (no support)

Comment: This is not currect. Can be trusted even if triggered by code.

Comment: At least with the AmazonKids browser (based on Chrome 94), there are events (e.g. touchstart) that have `isTrusted === true` but are unable to start audio.play() because they are not initiated by a `user-gesture`. But maybe that's just a bug or a user-gesture is something more complex than just 'triggered-by-user'.

Comment: @Nadav is correct. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656858/why-does-calling-window-scroll-give-a-trusted-event

Answer (score 15):

**[Workaround]** Javascript: Check if `event.screenX` & `event.screenY` are non-zero.

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.screenX && e.screenX != 0 && e.screenY && e.screenY != 0){
         alert("real button click");
       }   
}
```

> When the user clicks on button, it would have some real screenX and
>   screenY based on the button position. But when you do it from code -
>   it would be zero

Comment: hmm...let me give it a shot. Meanwhile can you please explain me how does it work?

Comment: When the user clicks on button, it would have some real screenX and screenY based on the button position. But when you do it from code - it would be zero.

Comment: @Vijay Of all the solutions I tried, `e.isTrusted` or `e.originalEvent` or 'e.which' which all fail when we fire a DOM click like `$("#button")[0].click();`  Your's is the only solution which works across all scenarios and combination of clicks. But unfortunately it doesn't work for keyboard clicks. But anyways +1 for a clean and simple solution.

Comment: Best shot. Thanks

Comment: Does not work with `focus` event even if triggered by a mouse click

Answer (score 4):

I know how to do it in jQuery

you can use the event object by checking `e.isTrigger`

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kushal812/q3q07enp/)

```js
$(".lol").click(function(e){
    console.log(e)
    alert("Is triggered: " + (e.isTrigger ? true:  false))
})

$(".trigger-lol").click(function(e){
    $(".lol").trigger("click")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lol">lol</div>
<div class="trigger-lol">Trigger lol</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Like i told in my Question I am using pure Js event and triggers. Had i been using jQuery I would'nt have posted this question.

Comment: @bhavya_w This answer helps those who may have the same question as you but can use jQuery.

Comment: To add on above, one can check jquery source codes and check for implementation and repeat it in his custom javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This working for me

```
if ((event.originalEvent.isTrusted === true && event.originalEvent.isPrimary === undefined) || event.originalEvent.isPrimary === true) {
    //Hey hooman it is you
    //Real CLick
}
```