# Why does calling Window.scroll() give a trusted event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a Chrome extension that needs to produce human-like mouse and keyboard behavior (specifically, generate events that have a `isTrusted` value of `true`). I can do everything I need except for scrolling with the `chrome.debugger` APIs.

But it seems that the `Window.scroll()` method is sufficient for this purpose up to Chrome 52 and Firefox 48.0a1. This can be observed by attaching an event listener to the page as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) { 
    console.log("event trusted? " + event.isTrusted);
});
```

and then running something like `window.scroll(0, 10);` in the developer console. This will log `event trusted? true` to the developer console.

My question is: why is this the case? Shouldn't the `isTrusted` property be `false` in this case since the scroll event was clearly generated by a script?

Answer (score 17):

This is by specification, per the [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted):

> NOTE: *[`isTrusted`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted) is a convenience that indicates whether an [event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event) is [dispatched](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch) by the user agent (as opposed to using [`dispatchEvent()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-dispatchevent)). The sole legacy exception is [`click()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-click), which causes the user agent to dispatch an [event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event) whose [`isTrusted`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted) attribute is initialized to false.*

Also, in the [DOM Level 3 Events Specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#trusted-events):

> #### [3.4. Trusted events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#trusted-events)
>
> Events that are generated by the [user agent](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#user-agent), either as a result of user interaction, or as a direct result of changes to the DOM, are trusted by the [user agent](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#user-agent) with privileges that are **not afforded to events generated by script through the [`createEvent()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createevent) method, modified using the [`initEvent()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-initevent) method, or dispatched via the [`dispatchEvent()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-dispatchevent) method.** The [`isTrusted`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted) attribute of trusted events has a value of `true`, while untrusted events have a [`isTrusted`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted) attribute value of `false`.

Thus, `isTrusted` only reflects if the event has been dispatched or created artificially using `createEvent`, `initEvent`, or `dispatchEvent`. Now, look at the definition of `Window.scroll` per the [CSSOM View Module Editor's Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scroll):

> When the ***`scroll()`*** method is invoked these steps must be run:
>
> [...]
>
> 2. If invoked with two arguments, follow these substeps:
>
> [...]
>
> 12. [Perform a scroll](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#perform-a-scroll) of the viewport to *position*, *document*’s root element as the associated element, if there is one, or null otherwise, and the scroll behavior being the value of the `behavior` dictionary member of *options*.

Nowhere in the method is an artificial event created with `createEvent`, `initEvent`, or `dispatchEvent`, thus the value of `isTrusted` is `true`. Note that using `Window.scroll` still triggers the event handler because it integrates with the event loop, and a `scroll` event is emitted when a viewport or element is scrolled. This *does not*, however, use `createEvent`, `initEvent`, or `dispatchEvent`.

Using the `isTrusted` event isn't a sure-fire way of detecting whether a script generated an event. It only detects if an event has been created and dispatched with `createEvent`, `initEvent`, or `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `*.scroll` or changing the `scrollTop` property does not construct the event correctly. As you can see in the example the `isTrusted` is `false` if I create the event on my own. I think it is a bug in the Engine

```js
"use strict";
var event = new Event('scroll');

//target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
//target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
//target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture, wantsUntrusted  ]); // Gecko/Mozilla only
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log(e.isTrusted);
}, false);

console.log('JS engine event:');
window.scroll(10, 10);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Selfmade event:');
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Another event triggered by changing the scrollTop property:');
  window.scrollTop = '20px';
}, 2000);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10000px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```