# Is there a way to know if "blur" was called by "element.blur()" or if it was "actual" blur?

Tags: javascript, blur

So, I have a simple question and I actually already wrote it in the title. :) But I will repeat it one more time, just to be completely clear. And the questions is:

Is there a way to know if "blur" was called by "element.blur()" or if it was "actual" blur? By saying "actual" I mean, clicking on some random area to make input lose focus, or by clicking TAB. :)

Comment: [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) apparently [won't help here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462125/1048572)

Comment: Why exactly do you care?

Comment: I care because I have a case where contenteditable(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) thing is used and value should be "committed/added" only once "enter" button is clicked and canceled on blur. But thing is that on "enter" that "contenteditable" element should lose focus and I am doing it by calling "element.blur()" on enter. And it causes blur event handler to be triggered and that handler cancels that change what was made by "enter" :) So, that's exactly my case here :)

Comment: By "enter button clicked", you mean "enter key pressed"? But I don't see why blurring a contenteditable content would cancel (reset?) the edit. OK, even when that is what you want, you could simply disable the blur handler when committing the edit (before calling `element.blur()`).

Comment: yes, enter key pressed. :) And why blur should reset, it's just a requirement, I am not doing this for fun :) 

And regarding disabling blur handler, it will not work, because I need this blur to actually happen, but it just should act a bit differently. Inside blur handler I need to have something like this:
https://pastebin.com/7mmBzBSQ

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do `onEnter(e) { element.contentEditable = false; commit(element.innerHTML); element.onblur = null; element.blur(); /* do blur-enter things */; }` and in the `onblur` handler just do the blur-blur things. Or, if you insist that you do the things in the blur handler, you can just set that `blurFromEnter` flag in the enter handler, right before calling `element.blur()`.

Comment: well... that "element.blur()" will also trigger "blur" event handler, or I just don't understand something here... I mean, I don't understand actually how setting this: element.onblur = null; element.blur(); will not trigger blur handler? I tried it here: https://jsfiddle.net/8pc0q895/ 

Thing is that I actually don't care about "onblur" thing here. I even don't need separate onblur handler, because I need actual blur to happen once element blurs. Actually I just need to know if there is not "hackish" way of recognizing "different" blurs inside blur event handler. That is my questions :)

Comment: Instead of `elem.onblur = null;` you'd do `elem.removeEventListener('blur', handleBlurEventListener);`, it depends on how you installed the handler. I imagined [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8pc0q895/1/)

Comment: and flaging enter is also not a solution here. Because there could be more cases like this. I mean, what if there will be need to implement other key handlers? like esc, shift and etc and each of them should work similar to enter? I mean, I don't want to write flags for each key and handling same flag for all keys also could cause troubles. :) so, that's why I am looking for "clean" solution(if clean solution is possible of course) :)

Comment: Actually flags (or any other indicator of the current *state*) is the clean solution. You need as many states as you want to have different cases in the blur handler. Of course multiple keys could cause the same state transition if they work the same.

Comment: thanks for working example :) but setting and removing onblur handler looks a bit "hackish". I know it does the job, but it's just feels wrong. But maybe there is no other way, I don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You should attach the blur event to the specific element you want.

An example would be:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" />

function handleBlur(event){
  console.log(event.target); // outputs: <input id="myInput" type="text">
}

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);
```

This function will only be called when blur event occurs for that input only. Nevertheless, you could use event.target to see the element that triggered the blur event.

EDIT:
Tested only on Chrome, but the following achieves what you are requesting.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" />

function handleBlur(event){
    if(event.sourceCapabilities !== null){
    console.log('blur by user');
  }
  else{
    console.log('blur programmatically')
  }
}

var elem = document.getElementById('myInput');
elem.addEventListener('blur', handleBlur);

elem.focus();
elem.blur();
```

Try it online on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1z83axmm/2/).

Since each browser handles event differently though, my suggestion is to trigger a different, custom event to handle this case.

Comment: well this doesn't solve my problem. :) you just wrote simple example of the "blur". But I know how to handle "blur" event and how to do something "onblur". Thing is that I want to know it that "blur" was called by "usual" "blur" event, or by calling function element.blur() :) Something like this:

 <input id="someId" type="text" onblur="doSomething()"/>

var someId = document.getElementById('someId');

someID.blur();

function doSomething(){
    // do stuff
}
function whichBlurWasIt(e) {
//was it blur or element.blur()
}

someID.addEventListener("blur", whichBlurWasIt);

Comment: @tdk I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. It does not matter if the blur event was called by the element handler attached to it(ex. onBlur="doSomething") or programatically (ex. element.blur()), because they both do the same thing, which is simply triggering an event called 'blur'.

Comment: I do understand that it doesn't matter if it's called programmatically or "onBlur", I mean I know I will catch that in my blur event handler. But my question is, is it possible to know inside the event handler if it was called programmatically or by "onBlur" thing? :)

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. :) It seems to work, but yeah unfortunately, that "sourceCapabilities" seems to be not so "bulletproof" way of solving my issue... and you mentioned custom events, could you please tell more about this idea?

Answer (score -1):

ooooo there's 2 different types of blur, one is an event called blur or onBlur for jQuery users which is for 'out of focus' basically the user clicks it and then clicks somewhere else. That's onBlur. Another is blur the CSS filter value for the filter property.

So! There's a few ways to see if an element is 'out of focus' one is like this:

```
var blur = true;//we start off not focused 

element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    blur = true;
});

element.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    blur = false;
});
```

So basically the above is "If it's not focused we are blured, if we are out of focus we blur". (Feel I'm making this more complicated to understand?). Try using `element.blur()` and `element.focus()` in the console and see what happens!

Another method is simply to check that the active element (focused element) is not your element.

```
document.getActiveElement.id !== element.
```

In jQuery there is a `:focus` prop you can use in the selector like so `$('element:focus')` which is also handy for `:checked` to get a checked radio button `$('input[type="radio"]:checked')`

Unfortunately though I don't think there's a way to see if another tab has been click. There probably is a way but in my experience, I had previously made a JS clock which I added to the title which appears as the tab's name. It didn't update when the tab was not opened so I think there's probably some more voodoo to look at to run your JS when the page is not in focus

Comment: thanks for the answer, but you are actually missing the point. Here is my idea: http://jsfiddle.net/1z83axmm

Comment: ohh you want to get the element in that event function? Then use `this` or `e.target`

Comment: I know I can get element inside handler, but it's not the case. I just want to know if blur was called programmatically (ex. element.blur()), or was it called by actual "blur"(when you just click in some random area and input goes out of focus). that's what I need :)

Comment: ohh right ok, I guess you could add a var for whenever you're calling `element.blur` or you could check to see if there was another element clicked but using bubbling or use the document to check if there was a focus event elsewhere. Why do you want to do that? What're you trying to do?