# How should I transfer a wheel or scroll event from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an absolutely positioned element over a scrollable area of my site. Clicking on this element will scroll the page down; it is for use by students with chromebooks that hide the scrollbars and do not provide a nice touchpad scrolling experience.

If a user (on Chrome) is scrolling manually, however, and the cursor slides over the absolutely positioned button, the page stops scrolling altogether. I would like for the page to scroll "normally" while the cursor is hovering over the button.

Capturing the wheel event and then making a new wheel event and dispatching it to the scrollable content does not work, I believe because `.isTrusted` is false.

As a workaround, I am capturing the wheel event and manually calling `.scrollBy` on the scrollable element. This does not scroll the page by the same distance though, and also results in jerky, stuttering scrolling.

```
elemScrollImg.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
      console.log("Img scroll: ", e)
      let deltaY = e.deltaY
      // Wanted to make a new WheelEvent to pass to the container
      // but isTrusted is false for "fake" events, and the page
      // apparently just ignores them :-/
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462125
      elemContent.scrollBy({
        top: deltaY,
        left: 0,
        // smooth scrolling apparently just makes it all worse,
        // esp. on touchpad scrolling.
        // behavior: 'smooth',
      })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seatag/a8m1kw20/58/

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using `position: sticky` to place the button inside the scrollable container, which allows wheel events to bubble up normally. This does not answer my question, but it does solve my problem.

```
.arrowWrapper {
  position: sticky;
    bottom: 15px;
    padding: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seatag/yb02c4sa/8/