# How to detect if user triggered scroll event vs window.scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `window.addEventListener` to handle scrolling events.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
}
```

I would like to disable that event handler when scrolling is triggered programatically by `window.scroll` vs user.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: A similar case for button click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794380/detect-if-button-click-real-user-or-triggered-by-a-script

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little useful trick...

```
if(event.isTrusted){

 // human gesture

} else {

// automated

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Promising but given `window.scroll` is called by the user, `event.isTrusted` always returns `true`. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: This isTrusted gives true if some one scroll it by schanging the scrollTop. So this has false positive: https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/rf9zakym/11/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656858/why-does-calling-window-scroll-give-a-trusted-event

Comment: Something like window.scrollTo(100,0) is not a human gesture.

Comment: Agreed, but it is triggered by a human so I believe it would register `isTrusted` as `true`.

Comment: Well then you'll have to set up a global flag and set it as required and where required.

Comment: Sadly, looks like few elegant options exist to distinguish between these events.

Comment: Btw, I see you are new to StackOverflow. Not all people ruthlessly downvote answers (I know it can be demotivating). Thanks for trying to help and welcome!