# Javascript equivalent for event.originalEvent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Can someone suggest me the Javascript cross-browser(should support IE 11 and new versions of Safari, Firefox, Chrome) equivalent for the JQuery's event.originalEvent property? I tried directly using event.originalEvent in my JS code, which is working perfectly fine on Chrome Browser, but not on Firefox.

I need this property to differentiate between an actual mouse click and programmatic click on an element, and I don't have the freedom to use JQuery.

**EDIT: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798519/5545297) seems to be doing the trick. Thanks everyone for helping out.**

Comment: does [event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) help? (with everything other than IE11)

Comment: Yes. But I want it to work across all browsers. event.isTrusted doesn't work on Safari as well.

Answer (score 3):

That's just the native `event`. Check its `isTrusted` property:

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via dispatchEvent.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.isTrusted) console.log('manual click');
  else console.log('script click');
});
setInterval(div.click.bind(div), 2000);
```

```html
<div>click</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But its not supported in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery event, `event.originalEvent` is equivalent to `Event object` which is passed to an event listener in javascript.

```js
{
  let jQEvent, vanillaEvent;
  $( "input" ).bind( "click", e => console.log( jQEvent = e.originalEvent ) );
  document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "click", e => console.log( vanillaEvent = e ) );
  
  document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "click", e => console.log( vanillaEvent === jQEvent ) );

  document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "click", e => console.log( `Triggered with manual: ${e.isTrusted}` ) );
}

  setTimeout( () => {
    document.querySelector( "input" ).dispatchEvent( (()=>{
      let event = new Event( "click" );
      event.screenX = 1;
      event.screenY = 1;
      return event;
    })() );
  }, 2000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit">
```

Don't use that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798010/javascript-detect-whether-an-event-is-triggered-by-user-and-not-programmatical/29798519#29798519). They are mutatable values.

Comment: If that's the case then directly checking the 'e' object should say whether click was programmatic or manual. But e is always populated either ways.

Comment: @RoshanPShajan use `.isTrusted` for checking that. If `.isTrusted` is true, that event was triggered with a manual click.

Comment: @RoshanPShajan Don't use that answer. They(properties) are mutatable. I add a snippet to mutate them.