# can a website disable javascript from executing .click() on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

im trying to automate some of my work I have to do every day which involves clicking a bunch of buttons sequentially.

I wrote a script and it has stopped working through a chrome extension.

I'm using the keypress library (https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) in a chrome extension to string together button clicks

ie - press "down", triggers clicking button 1, etc

Is it possible for a website to disable a chrome extension performing .click() on a button?

Some buttons on the page respond to my script simulating a .click() event, while others do not. I cannot figure out why

for example:

[image]

I'm trying to click the button nested under the div. I can access it with `$('#ember8628')[0].click()` but nothing happens.

When I click on it on the page, it works as expected.

To make sure I'm executing .click() on what I'm expecting to, I'm hovering over the readout in the dev tools when running `$('#ember8628')[0]`

Can you spot anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you expand on what the question is? There's no such thing as `CSS_Selector.click()`, so I'm not sure what you are asking. You can have JS trigger a click event, if you have an element reference. `document.querySelector('#ember8628').click()`.

Comment: A website can ignore programmatic clicks, yes. User-initiated clicks are flagged as "trusted". See [Detect Whether an Event is Triggered by User and not programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29798010/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, to be clear here, any javascript that is running on a website can tell if a click event has been trigger programatically or instead by user action, and can then choose to take action or not take action depending on that. The event isn't being ignored. It can just be responded to in different ways depending on if the event is programatic.

Comment: I was using CSS_Selector as a template name for any CSS selector I can use to find the element on the page I want to click

Comment: @AndyMercer Potayto, potahto. The end result of the event response in the case of programmatic clicks is that the click event does nothing. I call that "ignoring" the event, just like when you have an empty catch in a try/catch, I call that "ignoring" the error/exception. I'm not wrong, I'm just using the word differently from you.

Comment: this is super helpful. I take it there isn't a way around it?

Comment: *I wrote a script and it has stopped working through a chrome extension.* - do you mean: "I wrote a script through a chrome extension and it has stopped working"?

Comment: Unlikely, but worth a try: What does `console.log($('[id=ember8628]').length)` give you?  Could be if there's multiple elements with the same id then you're picking the wrong one?

Comment: It could be that your element doesn't have a `click()` event handler - if they're using `mouseup()` to "simulate" a click.

Comment: thats super interesting! Is there a way to see what the event handlers are on a button?

Comment: the length is 1

Comment: Could be the site has changed how  page is created such as dynamically inserting elements client side that previously were inserted server side making the timing of when you run your code more critical

Comment: @charlietfl at this point im just trying to click the first button on the page and see if I get any response from the browser. unfortunately nothing is happening

Comment: ...so I take it my code *did* work on Chrome...?