# Is it possible to know by what means the change called on HTML Select?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where the change on HTML Select can happened via trigger or by changing it manually.

My question is, if is it possible to know if that change is happened via trigger or by manually?

My sample code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#days', function(event)
{
    alert('Change happened');
});
$(function()
{
    $("#days").trigger('change');
});
```

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vSFqW/11/).

Comment: Can you really check your question for spelling before you send it here???

Comment: why you need this to know?

Comment: This might be to avoid automation.

Comment: this question is valid and have solution as well, why so much downvotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if event is triggered by a human](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human)

Comment: @OAD read the original question, before I corrected it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
event.isTrigger
```

is what you want to find it out, it is `undefined` when done manually and `true` when is fired by trigger method.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#days', function(event)
{
    alert(event.isTrigger);
    alert('Change happened');
});
$(function()
{
    $("#days").trigger('change');
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vSFqW/12/)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a jquery event `change` on  the select element. There is a key named `isTrigger` you can use it:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select#days', function(event) {
  var ev = event.isTrigger || event.type;
  $('pre').html('isTrigger ::::'+ ev);
});
$(function() {
  $("#days").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="days" name="days">
  <option value="0">- Select day -</option>
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `event.originalEvent` too.

Eg.

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <span id="span1">Span 1</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#span1").on("click", function(event){

     if (event.originalEvent) {

        alert("A Human Clicked on span1!");

    } else {
        alert("A Human Created Bot Clicked on span1!");
    }

});

botFn = function(){

     $("#span1").trigger("click", function(event){
            if (event.originalEvent) {

        alert("A Human Clicked on span1!");

    } else {
        alert("A Human Created Bot Clicked on span1! after 2 seconds!");
    }
  });

}

setTimeout(botFn, 2000);
```