# Passing parameters to $(window).on('resize') when using .trigger('resize')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-trigger

I need a reliable way to detect if `$(window).on('resize')` has been fired by user interaction or by a jQuery `.trigger` call.

I've tried the following, but I don't seem to get the parameters back in the function call:

```
$(window).trigger('resize',[true]);

function prepareOnResize(e, triggered){ console.dir(triggered); }
$(window).on('resize',prepareOnResize);
```

Triggered seems to return the width of the screen, so I tried the following, also to no avail:

```
$(window).trigger('resize',[true]);

function prepareOnResize(e, width, height, triggered){ console.dir(triggered); }
$(window).on('resize',prepareOnResize);
```

In that instance triggered comes back `undefined`.

I'm at a loss here -- any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That first example should work. [It worked ok for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0wqrq0z5/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery puts a property `isTrigger` in the event object, which you can test:

```
function prepareOnResize(e){ 
    if (e.isTrigger) {
        console.log('resize via jQuery trigger');
    } else {
        console.log('resize by user');
    } 
}
```

Alternatively you can use `e.originalEvent`, which jQuery only the native event object has, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human):

```
function prepareOnResize(e){ 
    if (!e.originalEvent)
        console.log('resize via jQuery trigger');
    } else {
        console.log('resize by user');
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but for the `resize` event it seems to always be set to `3` :\ Seems the `resize` event is handled differently by browsers than typical events like `click` or `mouseover`

Comment: Might be browser dependent, because it works for me. I added an alternative in my answer.

Comment: Tried originalEvent as well -- comes back undefined every time, regardless of how it the event was triggered.

Comment: I get the impression you have some other code or jQuery plug-ins that are responsible for this. Try with a new test page, without jQuery, and see if the property is set. Have you shared all the relevant code in your question?

Comment: I think you're right -- went digging around a bit more after your comment and came across a jquery.resize.js plugin hidden away in our site's architecture. Thanks for the help! I think I can take it from here :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following;

Javascript... on dom ready...

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('resize', function(event, param1) {

  console.log("Window resized event triggered by...");

  if (typeof param1 === 'undefined') // could also do if(param1) to test for false
    console.log("System Event");
  else
    console.log("User Event");

   // Another way to check is to check the originalEvent property
   // if (e.originalEvent === undefined) alert ('triggered by code');
   // else alert ('triggered by system');

});

setTimeout(function() {
  $window.trigger("resize", ["Custom"]);
}, 2000);
```

This is more or less what you were trying in your code, and it will distinguish the 2 types of events.

I also made a jsFiddle so you can see:
https://jsfiddle.net/sysdevcode/4w3b8e14/

To make it work on your code

```
$(window).trigger('resize',[true]);

function prepareOnResize(e, width, height, triggered){ console.dir(triggered); }
$(window).on('resize',prepareOnResize);
```

You need to change the order of the params on the `prepareOnResize()` function, 
as `$(window).trigger('resize',[true]);` equates to the [true] being sent as the "width" param in your function. you wold need to do, for instance:

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.trigger('resize',[ $window.width(), $window.height(), true ]);
```

then

```
function prepareOnResize(e, width, height, triggered){ ... }
```

will work, but if you don't need to pass any params, then the `e.isTrigger` of the code above is probably a bit more elegent.

Comment: You have error code. Check `console.log(Window ...)`

Comment: Thanks Robert, was copy from fiddle and didn't notice.. rectified

Comment: Thanks for the info, @DevOps ! Wasn't aware of the ordering behavior of parameters. Good to know :)

In case anyone was wondering, I've ended up using `e.originalEvent` to handle this issue. After nixing that bothersome plugin that was hijacking my native resize event, everything works much cleaner now :)