# Check if click event was made by user or a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `$(el).click();` to make click event. (Basically button was clicked by JS, not user).

Is there a away to detect if that click was done by user, or by script?

Comment: You should start with the doc on events objects http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: `e.originalEvent` if it's defined the click is human:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human/6692173#6692173

Comment: You can also check `e.which` which will be undefined if called via code: https://jsfiddle.net/wfonfej6/