# jQuery - detect change event triggered programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `change` event for when a user changes a given `SELECT` element. However the event may also be triggered by a third party script. What I want to do is detect whether the event was triggered programmatically or by the user.

I have tried the accepted solution in this question [Check if event is triggered by a human](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human)
But note the JSFiddle in this answer is for a `click` event rather than a `change` event.

To demonstrate I amended the fiddle and created this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Wv/231/

If you try this in latest Firefox or Chrome, you will see that the alert `human` is being shown even when the event was triggered programmatically.

I have tried `event.originalEvent.isTrusted` but that doesn't work in all browsers. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I have added mouseenter and mouseleave events. The idea is that it's a human if the click coincided with a mousepointer being over the element. See:
http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Wv/232/

```
$("#try").mouseenter(function(event) {
    mouseover = true;
});
// ... etc.
```

I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some vague difference between click and emulated click using this code:

```
$(document).on('change', "#try", function (event) {
    //some difference appear in the next line
    console.log(event.delegateTarget.activeElement);
    //no difference
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        alert('not human')
    } else {
        alert(' human');
    }
    event.delegateTarget = null;//doesn't help

});

$('#click').click(function (event) {
    $("#try").click();
});
```

Click on the checkbox logs `<input id="try" type="checkbox">`.
Click on the button logs `<button id="click">`.
But...
Run `$("#try").click();` from console before any clicks logs `<body>` and after the click result of the last click.
Generally JS can always fake any client event. So `isTrusted` is never trusted.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the **click** event as well, and modify a variable. The **change** event seems indeed to be quite similar wheter it's a real click or a script triggered click, but the **click** on **#try** event won't be the same. And since **click** is triggered before **change**, you have time to set a switch. 
Like this for example:

```
var realClick;
$("#try").change(function(event) {
  console.log('change')
  if (!realClick) {
    alert('not human')
  } else {
    alert(' human');
  }
```

});

```
$("#try").click(function(event) {
  console.log('click')
  // originalEvent is one way, but there will be many differences
  if (event.originalEvent) {
    realClick = true;
  } else {
    realClick = false;
  }
});

// Since this is called from outside, better not put 
// any controls here.
$('#click').click(function(event) {
  $("#try").click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xjjmo09/3/

Answer (score 1):

What really worked for me is:

```
if ((event.originalEvent.isTrusted === true && event.originalEvent.isPrimary === undefined) || event.originalEvent.isPrimary === true) {
    //Hey hooman it is you
    //Real CLick
}
```

Tested with jQuery version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can easily detect whether the click event on the button is actually triggered by mouse click or not. By doing,

```
$('#click').click(function(ev) {
    if (ev.which !== undefined && ev.button !== undefined) {
        $("#try").click();
    }
});
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Wv/233/)

*Note: Beware of either `ev.which` or `ev.button` could result in `0` on some browser for left-click.*

Answer (score 0):

You can check for if `event.srcElement` (which is source element on which event is triggered) is equal to `event.currentTarget` something like:

```
$("#try").change(function(event) {console.log(event,event.target,event.currentTarget,event.srcElement)
    if (event.currentTarget=== event.srcElement) {
        alert(' human')
    } else {
        alert(' not human');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Wv/234/