# How to check a select box is triggered manually or through .trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a select box and I've attached an event listener like below

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
  console.log("Changed")
})
```

This callback function will triggered if I manually change the select box and through jQuery using **trigger** method

```
$('#select').trigger('change');
```

So my requirement comes here, is there any way to check inside the change event listener whether the event is triggered **manually** or through **.trigger('change')** method

what I need exactly is,

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
  if(eventtriggeredmanually){
    console.log("Changed");   // need to do some logics if it is triggered manually not through .trigger('change') method
  }
})
```

Comment: a bit unclear `is there any way to check` ?

Comment: I will make a edit

Comment: if you want to distinguish between them then you can set custom data like `$('#select').data("manuallyTriggered", true)` before firing the `$('#select').trigger('change')` statement and in your event listener code you can check this data to make the difference.

Comment: This can be done, but i need better answer.

Comment: exactly what I am looking for. Thx @guradio

Answer (score 0):

Not any easy fixes.

My recommendation is to make two event handlers:

```
$('#select').on('changeProg', function(){
  console.log("Changed through code")
  toDo()
})
$('#select').on('change', function(){
  console.log("Changed manually")
  toDo()
})
function toDo(){ ... }
```

where you then use the first when you want to trigger through code

```
$('#select').trigger('changeProg');
```

Comment: any better solution than this.

Comment: got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human

Comment: thanks for your answer.