# How to check if the focus event is triggered programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if the focus event is triggered programtically or by human ?

I am writing the part of the script

```
    jQuery( document ).on( 'focus', '#song_artist_focus', function(event) {
                if(event.originalEvent === undefined ){
                 alert('I am not human');
                 return;}
                alert('I am human') ;
           });
```

And when i call this script  programtically like this

```
jQuery('#song_artist_focus').focus();
```

It still shows that event is triggred by human. Please help ?

### UPDATE

I checked this solution [Check if event is triggered by a human](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human).  But doesn't work on focus events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if event is triggered by a human](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692031/check-if-event-is-triggered-by-a-human)

Comment: Too fast to "mark as Duplicate" @VivekDoshi

Comment: Its working please try again , and given answer is same as in the above question

Comment: @VivekDoshi Sorry man, This is embarrassing. It is working now. But when i checked it, It didn't work. maybe i was doing something wrong. But i am using adeneo's solution in my script That looks better. thanks :)

Comment: I was also able to give the first answer , but it was already given in other question , no issue , you got your answer , that matters. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `focus` event doesn't bubble.
jQuery fixes that with a little magic to make it more like the other events, but it still doesn't quite work like an event that naturally bubbles.
To fix the problem, use the `focusin` event instead, as it bubbles, and do `.trigger('focusin')`

```js
jQuery(document).on('focusin', '#song_artist_focus', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
    console.log('I am not human');
  } else {
    console.log('I am human');
  }
});


jQuery('#song_artist_focus').trigger('focusin');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="song_artist_focus">
```

Answer (score 2):

Html :

```
<input type='text' id='try' >try
<button id='click'>Click</button>
```

jQuery :

```
$("#try").focus(function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        console.log('not human')
    } else {
        console.log(' human');
    }
});

$('#click').click(function(event) {
    jQuery('#try').focus();
});
```

Try it , you will get expected result.

Comment: . I tried it myself but didn't work. But now it is working ,Thanks for your help

Comment: @beginner , no problem man , m happy that you got my point and also that you got your answer.