# Get Event That Caused Change Event in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to pass the event that caused a change event to the change event function? I basically have a method that programmatically clicks a radio button. This calls the change function and I need to know if the original click was done by a human or done programmatically.

```
// This will trigger a change event on both input names menu1 and menu2.
$("#menu1").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu2A").click();
});

$("input [name='menu1'], input [name='menu2']").on("change", function(e) {
    var inputName = $($(e)[0].target).attr("name");
    if (inputName === "menu2") {
      // This is where I want to check that the click event was initiated by a human.
    }
});
```

I tried creating a `$("input[name='menu2'].on("click", function...)` that calls `e.preventDefault()` to check the click event, but that didn't work. It hit the change function before it hit the click function. This is why I figured I needed to check the click event within the change event function.

Comment: How your click event call your change event ?

Comment: Is easy when event name and element event triggered on are the same. Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: you can't put a event-object (in your case `e`) and put it into a jquery object. maybe you want `$(e.target)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough context to understand your end goals, but if you would prefer that the change event for `menu2` is not triggered when clicking on `menu1`, you can modify how you are setting `menu2` to be selected:

```js
// This will trigger a change event on input name menu1 only, NOT menu2
$("#menu1").click(function() {
  $("#menu2").prop("checked", true);
});


$("input[name=menu1], input[name=menu2]").change(function(e) {
  var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(inputName);
});

$("#clear").click(function() {
  $("input[name=menu1], input[name=menu2]").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' id="menu1" name="menu1">Menu 1
<input type='radio' id="menu2" name="menu2">Menu 2
<button id='clear'>Clear</button>
```

Comment: @LBecker does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed an even better answer here, using the event.originalEvent object:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6692173/2802014

Have you tried this?

```
var eventstore;
$("#menu2A").on('focus blur',function(e){
 if(e.which){
  eventstore='human';
 }
});
```

then you test if eventstore='human' inside of your "on change" (don't forget to set eventstore to 0 after that)